# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.defaultProps.allowFrontScaling)

Tags: react-native

Getting this issue when trying to load an app on android for react native (it works on ios )

It Seems like importing `'react-native'` isn't working. I've run `npm install`

This is the file that is causing the error:

```
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import DebugConfig from './DebugConfig'
import AppConfig from './AppConfig'

// Allow/disallow font-scaling in app
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = AppConfig.allowTextFontScaling

if (__DEV__) {
  // If ReactNative's yellow box warnings are too much, it is possible to turn
  // it off, but the healthier approach is to fix the warnings.  =)
  console.disableYellowBox = !DebugConfig.yellowBox
}
```

Comment: Try Changing `Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = AppConfig.allowTextFontScaling ` to `Text.allowFontScaling = AppConfig.allowTextFontScaling  `. If this isnt working then you must set explicitly the allowFontScaling = false on all Text instances.

Comment: that worked, thank you so much

Comment: If it worked , Mark my answer as correct ! Thanks

Comment: Can I do that? I'm not sure how to mark as correct

Comment: I have added the answer below for your convenient, there will be an Up arrow and Down Arrow on Left Side of the Answer, If your satisfied with my answer press on UpArrow, which will give an upvote for my answer ! And also there will be an tick mark at the bottom of those arrows, if you click on this , then the answer will be marked as correct ! Appreciate your feedback !

Answer (score 6):

Tested on React Native 0.57.5

Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling is undefined in 0.57.5
so I tried the following one.

```
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Changing

```
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = AppConfig.allowTextFontScaling
```

To

```
Text.allowFontScaling = AppConfig.allowTextFontScaling .
```

If this isn't working then you must set explicitly the allowFontScaling = false on all Text instances